# Problem in Installation of old version of Dotnetnuke

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

I am working on a very old project developed using Dotnetnuke version 4.4.0. After configuration of database I face with this error "Connection Error(s):
You must choose a Database Type". I have searched a lot but there is no information about this error on the web. Please hence that I am new to the dotnetnuke and windows related tools for web development such as IIS and ...

More information: dotnetnuke version 4.4.0, windows 10  and sql server 2008 r2

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing a clean DNN 4.4.0 and compare the connection strings (there are 2!) with your web.config file.